# Загрузка и выгрузка из базы данных Sqllite3 в tkinter с сохранением стиля

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter, style

Уважаемые господа, я практикуюсь в языке Python и SQL с использованием библиотек Sqllite3 и tkinter. У меня возник важный вопрос который не могу решить и с которым обращаюсь сюда за советом. Готового кода не прошу - дайте лишь материал для ознакомления или поясните нюансы возможно ли реализовать мою задумку.
Ситуация следующая:
Есть к примеру файл word в котором размеченный текст - где-то выделены заголовки жирным, где-то списки нумерованные, где-то гиперссылки и т.д. Есть область в tkinter куда хотелось бы отображать информацию из БД. Интересует - возможна ли каким-то образом загрузка в БД с сохранением стиля текста (жирный, списки нумерованные) и последующая выгрузка с применением этих стилей.
В данный момент я могу реализовать эту идею без БД с помощью ручной работы над текстом, но это большой объём текста (кода) - хотелось бы упростить задачу.
Подскажите..

Comment: Пока по описанию слишком всё расплывчато. Лично мне не понятна последовательность необходимых действий; что и куда сохраняется, выгружается и т д.  Вам нужно взять всё из файла MS Word, запихнуть в БД и затем отобразить всё это в tkinter, но при этом сохранить все стили текста?

Comment: @mrBars1k да, вы поняли всё верно. Загрузить разные текста с разными стилями в БД потом выгрузить в tkinter и сохранить их стили

Answer (score 0):

Есть вопрос на StackOverflow про [форматирование текста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724936/copying-formatted-text-from-text-widget-in-tkinter), а также на PythonGides про [написании Word документов в tkinter](https://pythonguides.com/create-word-document-in-python-tkinter/), надеюсь они Вам помогут.

Comment: отличная статья про создании Word через tkinter - мне необходима обратная конвертация, загрузить в tkinter страницу из Word в её текущем состоянии

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, задача реализуемая, но достаточно муторная и требует много деталей.

Возможно эти данные станут для Вас полезными:

• Для работы с *MS Word* документами, есть библиотека **docx**:

`pip install python-docx`

• Для работы с SQL, я бы рекомендовал **postgresql** и библиотеку **psycopg2**:

`pip install psycopg2`

*sqlite3* поддерживает меньше типов данных, менее гибок и масштабируемый, поэтому и рекомендую сразу использовать *postgresql*, но в данной задаче, возможно, это и не обязательно. Различий в синтаксисе СУБД минимально, перейти легко.

• У библиотеки **docx** есть возможность распознавать стиль слова, так что учитывать разницу форматирования можно, но нет типа данных, который бы явно указал, что текст жирный, курсив и т д.
Думаю, нужно написать собственную функцию, которая будет добавлять идентификатор стиля для каждого слова. Допустим, как в *html* - теги `<b>Жирный</b` или `**Жирный**` такого вида.

В общем, можно придумать собственные идентификаторы стиля или использовать проверенные методы.

• Проходимся по всем словам документа циклом или своим способом, проверяя каждое слово на предмет стиля и, если такой имеется, то функция должна возвращать слово в уже отформатированном виде.

Затем добавляем полученный результат, в котором весь текст документа отформатирован под Ваши условия, в базу данных.

• Далее в **tkinter** добавляем всё полученное в том представлении, которое Вы сделаете, а форматирование текста будет таким же образом, только не добавляя в БД, а извлекая из него и добавляя в программу.

### Условный пример:

---

**Содержимое файла test.docx:**

Пример1

**Пример2**

*Пример3*

---

**Проходим функцией и в БД будет:**

`Пример1`

`<b>Пример2</b>`

`<i>Пример3</i>`

---

**Проходим другой функцией по словам из БД и делаем соответствующий вид уже в *tkinter***

Это тот способ, который пришёл мне в голову, но 100% есть решение намного лучше и практичнее, но я не нашёл. Возможно, у меня получилось натолкнуть Вас на нужные мысли.